# Spring MVC - handling form best practice - write specific form class or use entity class?

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc

Learning Spring (3.1.0) and Hibernate (4.1.1). Just wondering what most developers do when handling form data. When writing a JSP that contains a form used to submit data, do you normally write a class specific to the input fields on that form and process that server-side or do you just use your entity classes and bind them to the elemtns on the form?

Say I have an application that has 3 entity classes: Location, StoreType and Store (a Store has a StoreType and a Location). On the form on the /CreateStore JSP page I have a dropdown select box with all Locations, another dropdown select box with all the StoreTypes and other text input fields with store name, store manager etc.

Do you create a CreateStoreForm class with a List locationNames, List storeTypes, String storeName etc. and put this on the model? Or do you just put all the various entity classes on the Model separately? I have been using the latter approach but I am thinking that the former may be better especially for re-populating the screen when a user makes consecutive requests to the same screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good to have a class that maps form, then write a util method which converts from form class to the actual model class which Hibernate would be using to do operations.

And for the drop-down, you can use `@ModelAttribute` on a method separately which returns the list and which you will be able to use in form. And you won't need to add it to your form class or entity class.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @ModelAttribute("productsList")
    public Collection<Product> populateProducts() {
        return this.productsService.getProducts();
    }
    // @RequestMapping etc omitted for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the approaches you have mentioned is good. But choosing them is based upon your requirement.
In the case you have mentioned in your question the second approach is better since the two list you are passing locationNames and storeTypes are just the reference fields. And in your actual model class (having storeName and storeManager fields) must be containing the id of both location and storeType.

So when you submit the form only the model class having store properties is going to be stored in the database. The other list fields are just reference data and you will not be storing it in database along with the other fields.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.